# Mobx don't update observable array

Tags: reactjs, mobx

I've store with obersable array :

`@observable list = [];`

And i've methode for remove an item in my array :

@

```
@action remove(_id) {
  const presentation = this.list.find(item => _id === item._id);
  this.list.remove(presentation);
  console.log(this.list.slice()); // Don't update, @action log : spliced 'PresentationsStore@2.list': index 2, added 0, removed 1
}

@action findUserPresentations(userId) {
  return this.list.filter(item => userId === item.userId);
}
```

My console.log() work nice (return new array without item), but my container with @observable isn't update :

```
@observer
@inject('user', 'presentations')
class MyPresentationsContainer extends React.Component {

  get presentations() {
    return this.props.presentations.findUserPresentations(this.props.user.id);
  }

  render() {
    return (
      <MyPresentations
        presentations={this.presentations}
      />
    );
  }
}
```

Anyone know if i need add other methode in `remove(_id)`  ?

Thank you !

Answer (score 2):

You can simply define the remove method as:

`action remove(_id) {
  const item = this.list.find(item => _id !== item._id)
  this.list.remove(item)
}`

The cause that your update is not working is that you are assigning a *new* array to `this.list`. Which is unnecessary, but not a problem it itself.

However, in your component, you store the reference to the list in the state when it is created. Now, after reassigning `this.list`, the list is updated, but your state is still pointing the old list. Storing references locally is an anti pattern, as you are basically creating redudant information, which causes your bug here.

Instead, you could better write

```
@observer
@inject('user', 'presentations')
class MyPresentationsContainer extends React.Component {

  get presentations() { 
     return this.props.presentations.findUserPresentations(this.props.user.id)
  }

  render() {
    console.log(this.presentations);
    return (
      <MyPresentations
        presentations={this.presentations}
      />
    );
  }
}
```

This prevents storing a copy of the old reference to the list.

Comment: Add @mweststrate ! Than you for your help. I've try to update my code, but same result : my container don't update. I've edit my first post with new code :)

Comment: My problem is probably with `.filter`

Comment: @s-leg3ndz Could you try and swap your decorators around? `@inject('user', 'presentations') @observer`

Comment: Hi Tholle, same result. But my problem is this array.filter() because he return new array :/

Comment: Please remove the `@action` decorator from `findUserPresentations`. it is not an action but a view on the data.

Answer (score 0):

the filter method basically returns a new array.

You can do this:

`this.list = this.list.filter(item => userId === item.userId);`